# How to properly remove .html from my URLs?

Tags: nginx, haproxy

I have a static site running on Nginx, very very basic, just serves the index.html on requests, my link trees all reference /page.html, but what I would like to do is remove the need for .html on non-index pages, so that a user can just go to https://url.com/page instead of having to go to https://url.com/page.html.

the site stands behind haproxy, which performs the HTTP to HTTPS redirect, and the non-WWW vs WWW subdomain redirecting, would it be best to remove this .HTML in HAProxy? or Nginx? what would the process for that be?

Comment: If it's just static html files on backend, then just rename them all stripping the .html extension and adjust all links in there accordingly.

Comment: @tbielaszewski this causes the file to be served as a download instead of being rendered.